# ExecutorService add tasks dynamically

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have ExecutorService for 10 tasks, and I want to handle e.g. 24 tasks. First 10 tasks I can add immediately, but when some task complete I want to add another one.

Is there some best practice, common approach or pattern to implement this behavior?

Comment: add tasks when you want. In your case, add all 24 tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executors have s queue¹ for keeping tasks while waiting for threads to become available to process them. You don't need to do anything special, just submit tasks to the executor as you please.

¹ This is not strictly true, and the queue may be limited. However in the general use case (unless otherwise indicated), the queue is unlimited and you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Kayaman. I think was inaccurate in my question. I want to say if I want to use fixedThreadPool(10), because I don't want to add all   processes imedeately. As I understand, in this case a new 10 processes will added only after all 10 tasks will finished.  Am I correct?

Comment: No, it means that you have 10 threads running and they will process any tasks that are available. If you have more than 10 tasks submitted to the executor, some tasks will wait in a queue for a thread to finish with its previous task and retrieve the next one from the queue. Don't use the word "processes" here, it's very misleading.